# How to close webview after the work is done in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-webview

I am using following code to render a webview:

```
const someHTMLFile = require('./somefile.html')
render() {
  return (
     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <WebView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          source={someHTMLFile}
          ref={( webView ) => this.webView = webView}
      />      
    </View>
  );
}
```

In this html file, there is a form which is automatically submitted when the webview loads (with some data sent from reactnative part of code) and in the end, the file is redirected to a specific url, where some processing is done (on the send data), and right now, it returns nothing. So the screen goes blank.

So, at this point, I want to close the webview and take the user back to my reactnative app.. So, how can I do that? any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Webview have onNavigationStateChange props which will give a foundation when webview loading starts or ends.

Therefore you can use these props to check current state or the current URL of webview and put some condition to close the webview.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <WebView
                style={{flex: 1}}
                onNavigationStateChange={(e) => {
                    console.warn("current state is ", JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
                    /** put your comdition here based here and close webview.
                     Like if(e.url.indexOf("end_url") > -1)
                     Then close webview
                     */
                }}
                source={someHTMLFile}
                onLoadEnd={()=>{
                /* add you work that you want to do after loading is done. */
                }}
                ref={(webView) => this.webView = webView}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am still facing an issue with this. The state is changed as soon as it redirect is started. I want to know when the redirect request is complete. So is there a way for that too?

Comment: Ok then you can use onLoadEnd or onLoad props of webview,  which is as
onLoad = {(event)=>{
Console.log(evebnt.nativeEvent)
}}

This can help you, as it runs after the complete page is loaded

Answer (score 4):

Closing `WebView` is basically equals to un-mounting the component. You can do conditional rendering to mount and un-mount the component. The usual behavior is to open up a `Modal` which has a `WebView` inside. When you are done with the `WebView` you can send a message to react and then close the modal. This will un-mount the modal and `WebView`.

You can use [`onMessage`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onmessage) prop to communicate between WebView and React-Native.

> A function that is invoked when the `webview` calls
>   `window.postMessage`. Setting this property will inject a
>   `postMessage` global into your `webview`, but will still call
>   pre-existing values of `postMessage`.

**Example**

```
_onMessage = (message) => {
   console.log(message);
}

render() {
  return (<WebView ref={(ref) => { this.webView = ref; }} onMessage={this._onMessage} ..otherProps />);
}
```

---

```
// In your webview inject this code

<script>
  window.postMessage("Sending data from WebView");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Make this props inside Webview Checkout Component :

```
<WebView    onMessage={event => event.nativeEvent.data === 'WINDOW_CLOSED' ? onClose() : onPaymentSuccess(event.nativeEvent.data)} />
```